# How I can get the location of the device if the GPS is off?

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I would like to get the latitude and longitude of a device, if the GPS is off, well hopefully can be a precise location

Comment: have you get location if GPS is Off

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi Yes, you can get it but not the current location. Try to use "Last Known Location" of Google Service (https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

Comment: @ zhelon i used this method but i am getting null value if my GPS is off

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi sorry, I don't remeber how I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the new `LocationClient` that is part of Google Play Services [Location API](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html). It uses a fused provider that automatically determines what is the best provider available at that moment. It also uses other sensors to get a more accurate location.

Answer (score 0):

you can get your location from three techniques  and each one called  Provider and each one  has  some pros and drawback and uses  you don't  care about it Google play services will  making it for you but you need to have good understand of that , the three ways is

from  GPS , Network , SIM(mobile device with sim)

and here some implementations of the techniques 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html